# css imageless transparent overlay

Tags: html, css

I would like to create something like on attached image using only CSS. Until now I have come-up with:

```
.block5-header:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    background: url({template_relativeimagepath}{template_imagesfolder}blocks/elipsa.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

But this solution requires to use a lot of different png images, as i have many different sizes of header blocks. I have tried to use pseudo elements with radial gradients, but to no avail. If there is some simpler solution please let me know ;)

Pic of what i would like to achieve. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIpg0.png

Comment: Can you update the link please.

Comment: try this one:
http://image.bayimg.com/496b2125d3e39f389a3ed066d01c2fb3b1ce510f.jpg

Comment: I'm working on a fiddle to show how to achieve this\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I used css `position`, `circles`, and `rgba`.

**[Pure CSS Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/WcLyA/1/)** (Fixed width)

**[It is also responsive to width changes](http://jsfiddle.net/WcLyA/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<header class="subNav">
  <span class="headCirc"></span>
  Something
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.subNav {
  width: 285px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #4679bd;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.headCirc {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -5%;
  display: block;
  width: 110%;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

What I did was positioned the circle absolutely inside of the header, I then gave the header an `overflow: hidden` to hide anything of the circle that came out of the box.

Comment: You are very welcome! Best of luck mate and I am glad I was able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to get the curved line but if you don't mind that you can try out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: are there any alternative ways of rescaling background transparent png image? For example to scale only width and leave height the same?

Comment: In css - set the height to % or em, maybe.